# Python http.client.HTTPConnection send in c#

Tags: c#, python, .net-core, python-requests, dotnet-httpclient

I'm looking for c# code snippet for the below python code. I didn't understand how to re write the code part "*conn.send()*"

```py
def add(self, data):
    self.conn.send(("%s\r\n" % hex(len(data))[2:]).encode('UTF-8'))
    self.conn.send(data)
    self.conn.send('\r\n'.encode('UTF-8'))
```

I am not able to find `conn.send`-like method in c# or RestSharp. how to write that in c#. below snipped is complete code for reference.

```
class ChunkedHTTPSend:
  def __init__(self, host, port, command, args):
    self.conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(host, port)
    url = '/%s' % command
    if len(args) > 0:
      url += '?%s' % urllib.parse.urlencode(args)
    print('URL: %s' % url)
    self.conn.putrequest('POST', url)
    self.conn.putheader('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked')
    self.conn.endheaders()

  def add(self, data):
    self.conn.send(("%s\r\n" % hex(len(data))[2:]).encode('UTF-8'))
    self.conn.send(data)
    self.conn.send('\r\n'.encode('UTF-8'))

  def finish(self):
    r = self.conn.getresponse()
    s = r.read()
    if r.status != 200:
      raise RuntimeError('FAILED:\n%s' % s.decode('utf-8'))
    else:
      return s.decode('utf-8')
    self.conn.close()
```

to understand better, how this python class is used to send request to server in chunk wise data, see below code snippet.

```
c = ChunkedHTTPSend("localhost", "8080", "uploaddocument", "filename.temp")
with open('filename.temp', 'rb') as f:
  while True:

          b = f.read(8)
          if len(b) == 0:
            break
          docCount, byteCount = struct.unpack('ii', b)
          totBytes += byteCount
          #print('docCount %s, byteCount %s' % (docCount, byteCount))
          bytes = f.read(byteCount)
          try:
            c.add(bytes)
          except:
            print('FAILED:')
            print(c.finish())
            raise
c.finish()
```

`c.add(bytes)` is called for every N no of bytes, each time `c.add(bytes)` called it send 3 requests. I would like to know what is this 3 requests meaning, and how we can do it in c#.

Note: Server side code is Java rest api, which is working fine with python and java client calls. So  no changes will be allowed in server side.

Now i'm trying to re-write this code part in c#.